# Does `activator new` create the correct Scala Play anatomy?

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

According to the [Scala Play application layout documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Anatomy) the anatomy looks as follows:

```
 app                      → Application sources
  └ assets                → Compiled asset sources
     └ stylesheets        → Typically LESS CSS sources
     └ javascripts        → Typically CoffeeScript sources
  └ controllers           → Application controllers
  └ models                → Application business layer
  └ views
```

When `activator new` is issued:

[image]

The `models` directory seems to be omitted:

#### Discussion:

Some Play examples contain a models directory, while this is not the case when `activator new` is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The folder `app` is equivalent to `src/main/scala` or `src/main/java` in a traditional Scala or Java project, so what resides under it is developer-defined.

On an aside, [SBT now supports Giter8](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/sbt-new-and-Templates.html#Giter8+support), so you could try generating a project using the [Play Scala Seed](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-seed.g8) if you would like to sense-check my answer.