# How to organize java and scala code in Play?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

`activator new`

results in:

```
Fetching the latest list of templates...



Browse the list of templates: http://lightbend.com/activator/templates
Choose from these featured templates or enter a template name:
  1) minimal-akka-java-seed
  2) minimal-akka-scala-seed
  3) minimal-java
  4) minimal-scala
  5) play-java
  6) play-scala
(hit tab to see a list of all templates)
>
```

The anatomy of `play-java` and `play-scala` looks as follows:

```
ls project-*/app
...-java/app:
controllers  filters  Filters.java  Module.java  services  views

...-scala/app:
controllers  filters  Filters.scala  Module.scala  services  views
```

According to [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Anatomy) documentation:

> You also have the option of using the default layout used by SBT and
> Maven. Please note that this layout is experimental and may have
> issues. In order to use this layout, you must disable the layout
> plugin and set up explicit monitoring for twirl templates:

```
build.sbt                  → Application build script
src                        → Application sources
 └ main                    → Compiled asset sources
    └ java                 → Java sources
       └ controllers       → Java controllers
       └ models            → Java business layer
    └ scala                → Scala sources
       └ controllers       → Scala controllers
       └ models            → Scala business layer
    └ resources            → Configurations files and other non-compiled resources (on classpath)
       └ application.conf  → Main configuration file
       └ routes            → Routes definition
```

**Discussion**

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42175703/does-activator-new-create-the-correct-scala-play-anatomy/42178504#42178504) one should combine the java and scala files? E.g.:

merge

```
...-java/app/controllers:
AsyncController.java  CountController.java  HomeController.java

...-scala/app/controllers:
AsyncController.scala  CountController.scala  HomeController.scala
```

to

```
.../app/controllers
AsyncController.java  CountController.java  HomeController.java
AsyncController.scala  CountController.scala  HomeController.scala
```

Is this the Play anatomy for combining java and scala classes or should a java and scala directory be created in the app/controllers folder?

The `routes` file that resides in the scala and java project are identical:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# An example controller showing a sample home page
GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index
# An example controller showing how to use dependency injection
GET     /count                      controllers.CountController.count
# An example controller showing how to write asynchronous code
GET     /message                    controllers.AsyncController.message

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put your `controllers`and `models` folders into an `app` folder, and put both scala and java files inside.

```
build.sbt            → Application build script
app                  → Application sources
 └ controllers       → controllers (java or scala)
 └ models            → business layer (java or scala)
 └ views             
public
conf
 └ application.conf  → Main configuration file
 └ routes            → Routes definition
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to special "combine" layout - you can use java and scala in the same packages.

Example:

```
package controllers;

public class MyJavaClass {

  public static String getName(){
    return "My Name";
  }
}
```

[image]